# Wordpress media upload : Error 500

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading, internal-server-error, http-error, server-configuration

When I try to upload images on multiple WP websites hosted on a particular server, via the Flash uploader, I get a **HTTP Error** written in red.

I know that this is a common problem, but the common solutions don't work for me. This is why I try to ask it as a new question.

Here is what I tried so far :

- Fresh WP copy
- Folder / file permissions on wp-content/uploads and .htaccess
- Delete .htaccess
- Switch to Regular uploader which leads me to a Internet Server Error 500 when I try to upload files
- Switch theme
- Disable all plugins
- The mod_security fix
- Tested the site on my local server, and **it did work correctly** but I have no idea why.

Thank you!